# How to resize a view based on its intrinsic content?

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I have a view with a multi-line label inside (subview). As I add dynamic text, I want the label as well as the parent view to grow in size so that all the text always appears without being truncated. This is something I've been struggling with for some reason. I want the outer view to push down any trailing views as it grows. How can I do this using xcode 9 swift 4?

Comment: iOS or macOS? What have you tried so far? Update your question with relevant code and clearly explain your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**step 1:** 
In storyboard put the label inside the view and give *number of lines* to '0'

**step 2:** 
give the label *top,bottom,leading,trailing* constraints to the view 
for example '0' spacing in all sides.

**step 3:** 
Now give the view *x,y positions and width* , no need to give the height of the view it will automatically infer it from the label.

The intrinsic property of the label will automatically pushes the height of the view with respective to the content.

Comment: I must have had my constraints setup wrong because my label text was not showing after it reached the bottom of the view. I put the view (and the enclosing label) inside of a StackView and everything works fine (it's basically doing what you've posted).